# Is the maximum value of this recursively defined function bounded?

Tags: limits, recursion

If we define $$f_1(x)=x^\frac{1}{x}$$
$$f_{n+1}(x)=x^\frac{1}{f_n(x)}$$
Then what is the value of the following
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} f_k \left( [f_k^\prime]^{-1}\left( 0\right)\right)$$ where $k\in\{\text{Odd numbers}\}$

That is to say what is the limit of the max value of $f_k$ as $k$ approached $\infty$

---

The first few values are as follows:

1. 1.44466786100977
2. 1.68566609644993
3. 1.84222035704638
4. 1.95368819730989
5. 2.03776143885044
6. 2.10376587133782
7. 2.15714616594055
8. 2.20131939907498

The ratio test and the root test are inconclusive.

---

I have no idea where to start with this, but this is basically only for fun so I may be out of my depth!

Comment: Have you found the first few values of $f_k \left( [f_k^\prime]^{-1}\left( 0\right)\right)$ to see if there is a visible pattern? Also, does the $-1$ mean the inverse function or the reciprocal? It is not at all obvious that the derivatives will be one-to-one functions. That is clearly not the case for $f_1'$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I will add the first few values I have found to the question, the notation you asked about is meant to mean the inverse of the derivative of $f_k$ this will need similar treatment to that needed to make $asin$ a valid function. **If in doubt use the wordy version underneath it is probably clearer**

Comment: You are still not clear. Do you mean you are restricting the domain of $f_k'$ so it is invertible near $x=0$? And what wordy version do you mean? If you mean "That is to say..." that is no more clear than the expression.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I am not sure if that is what I mean. $f_k \left( [f_k^\prime]^{-1}\left( 0\right)\right)$ is intended to mean the value of $f_k$ at $f_k$'s maximum